# an error keeps appearing when i try to turn my .py file into a exe

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am  using visual studio code on windows 10 and i'm trying to turn a tkinter python file file into an exe but an error keeps appearign i have tried multiple tutorials but nothing is working please help.

i have installed "pyinstaller" and when i enter "pyinstaller --onefile (filname).py" this error appears

pyinstaller : The term 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pyinstaller --onefile I_think.py
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pyinstaller:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: _i have installed "pyinstaller"_ Did you add its program directory to your windows `PATH` environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because you're installing Pyinstaller in your global Python installation. When typing the `pyinstaller` command, your system does not find the executable because it's not in your system's PATH.

There are two things you can do to resolve your issue.

1. Install `pyinstaller` inside a virtual environment. This will create a Python installation or "box" that is separate from your global install, and will be easier to use, and is good practice for larger projects.
   Navigate to your project folder and run the command `python -m venv <name>` to create a fresh virtual environment. Once this is done, activate the venv with `.\<name of venv>\Scripts\activate.bat` and run `pip install pyinstaller`. You then should be able to run your pyinstaller commands like normal.
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#how-venvs-work
2. Use the `python -m <module>` command. Since you installed Pyinstaller in your global installation, you can run that module using `python -m pyinstaller --onefile filename.py`

Comment: thank you for the reponse but when i enter python -m venv filename, this pops up.

Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Comment: @Arghj Have you not installed Python on your system at all yet?